# pass command line argument in vscode test runner script (index.ts)

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, glob

**Scenario:**

script in `package.json` file looks like:

`"test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js"`

this `runTest.js` then calls test runner script `src/test/suite/index.ts` . Source of this file is : https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension

In the index.ts, it uses source like:

```
    return new Promise((c, e) => {
    glob('**/**.test.js', { cwd: testsRoot }, (err, files) => {
```

Here, glob is pointing to the src files to consider for test run.

**Question:**

For specific reason, I don't want to test all files using regex like: `glob('**/**.test.js'`

I want to test ***specific*** file and I want to pass it by my test script in `package.json` file.

For ex: I want

`"test": "node ./out/test/runTest.js   Filename"`

And `glob()` in `index.ts` file will consider only this `Filename` for execution.

I need some help in this regards.

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to pass arguments from npm scripts inside package.json is via environment variables. The syntax is slightly different depending on the platform. The example below is for Windows.

```
"test": "set FileName=foo.js&node ./out/test/runTest.js"
```

The argument and the value is now awailable inside runTest.js in process.env

```
console.log(process.env.FileName);   //foo.js
```

Comment: cool ... thanks a lot. I got the idea. Let me check. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the `src/test/suite/index.ts` open your `package.json` file and search for the `"test"` script line and parse it for the arguments.

**Edit**

I needed something similar and added a file: `test-arguments.txt` next to `index.js` or maybe in `.vscode` folder if you use typescript.

Inside `index.js` I open the file and parse the arguments. I allow lines to be commented with `#`.

By adding this `test-arguments.txt` file to `.gitignore` I don't have to modify `package.json` and my team members can have different arguments.